# Pycharm SASS: output css in relative directory

Tags: npm, sass, pycharm

I'm trying to setup a file watcher in PyCharm for my SASS files. I've followed the official guide and it worked jsut fine (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#)

Now **I'd like to change the destination of the compiled CSS files to a specific folder, relative to the SASS file**. Basically, the output directory should be **`../css/`** when starting from the SASS file, because my structure looks like this:

```
app1/
    static/
        css/
            myfile.css
        sass/
            myfile.sass
app2/
    static/
        css/
            myfile2.css
        sass/
            myfile2.sass
```

I'm not sure I understand what values I should put in `arguments` and `output paths to refresh`. I'm currently using the default settings (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR4zh.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. For anyone struggling with the same issue, here's how I fixed it:

- Arguments = **sass\$FileName$:css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css**
- Output = **css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css**
- Working Directory = **$FileParentDir$**

Here's an image of the setup :

[image: File watcher Sass setup]